# How to access 'this' keyword inside of static method in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am not able to access 'this' keyword in my static method in react- native, when I try to access it, it's thrown me error like 'this.setState not a function'.

Here is my code.

```
static getShiftStatus = () =>{
        //for check shift start or not  
        Usermodal.getShiftStatus((isStatus) =>{
            this.setState({isShiftStart: isStatus}) //error occure here.
            console.log(a.state.isShiftStart)
        }) 
    }
```

Comment: Static methods aren't called on instances of the class, so if you just remove the `static` keyword it should work as expected.

Comment: Bind the method to the instance in the constructor?

Answer (score -1):

`this` in the inner function points to something else.
You need to capture the `this` from the outside function.

```
static getShiftStatus = () =>{

        var that = this;  // capture here

        Usermodal.getShiftStatus((isStatus) =>{
            that.setState({isShiftStart: isStatus})  // use it here
            console.log(a.state.isShiftStart)
        }) 
    }
```

Comment: But the inner function is an arrow function, so doesn't it use the `this` value from its containing context?

Comment: this can't be used under static function